# Проблема с Future и Callable. Ожидание ответа. Как обойти

Tags: java, многопоточность

Необходимо одновременно считывать множество файлов. Пока их было немного обходился обыкновенными потоками. Но т.к кол-во файлов увеличилось, возникла необходимость использовать пул потоков. Мысль следующая: В цикле читаются файлы и вызывают поток. И вот тут возникла проблема: Если чтение начинает читать большой файл, то всё по сути останавливается, т.к ожидается ответ. Смысл тогда всего этого пула, если по сути чтение файлов происходит по очереди? Пока не будет обработан большой файл,чтение следующих останавливается. Как можно обойти этот момент?

```
public class ReadFile
{
String s;
public ReadFile(String s) throws ExecutionException 
{
    this.s = s;
    // Определяем пул  потоков
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
     
     // Список ассоциированных с Callable задач Future 
    List<Future<String>>  futures = new ArrayList<>();

     // Создание экземпляра Callable класса
     Callable<String> callable = new CallableClass(s);

     //for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
         /*
          * Стартуем возвращаюший результат исполнения 
          * в виде объекта Future поток
          */
          Future<String> future = executor.submit(callable);
         /*
          * Добавляем объект Future в список для 
          * отображения результат выполнения (получение
          * наименования потока)
          */
         futures.add(future);
   //  }
     SimpleDateFormat sdf;
     sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss  ");
     for (Future<String> future1 : futures)
     {
         try {
             // Выводим в консоль полученное значение
             String text = sdf.format(new Date()) + future1.get();
             System.out.println(text);
         } catch (InterruptedException | 
                  ExecutionException e) {}
     }
     // Останавливаем пул потоков
     executor.shutdown();
}  

// Класс, реализующий интерфейс Callable
class CallableClass implements Callable<String>
{
    String s;
    public CallableClass(String s)
    {
      this.s = s;  
    }

    
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception 
    {
       // Thread.sleep(1000);
        
        readFromFile(s);
        return "From call: "+ s +". ThreadName: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" end";
    }
}
```

}

И в main вызывается в цикле ReadFile("Путь к файлу");

Comment: Выводить значение в консоль в потоке. Другими словами в `CallableClass`.

Answer (score 0):

В общем идея моя изначально была неверная. Ибо то, что нормально для потоков, для пула не подходит. Имею в виду что каждый раз вызывал ReadFile в цикле, с передачей пути файла. Для правильной работы надо передавать весь массив путей, из которых потом собственно и будет создан пул потоков. **Но и это не решило бы мою проблему.** Решение нашёл через CompletionService. Вот собственно сам рабочий код, может кто-то столкнется с такой же проблемой.

```
public class ReadFile
 {
  ArrayList<String> FileArray = new ArrayList<>();
  String s ="";

public ReadFile(ArrayList<String> FileArray) throws ExecutionException 
 {
    this.FileArray = FileArray;
    // Определяем пул из потоков
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    CompletionService<String> executorCompletionService = new   ExecutorCompletionService<>(executor);
     
     // Список ассоциированных с Callable задач Future 
    List<Future<String>>  futures = new ArrayList<>();
   

     for (int i = 0; i < FileArray.size(); i++){
         /*
          * Стартуем возвращаюший результат исполнения 
          * в виде объекта Future поток
          */
          Future<String> future = executorCompletionService.submit(new  CallableClass(FileArray.get(i)));
         /*
          * Добавляем объект Future в список для 
          * отображения результат выполнения (получение
          * наименования потока)
          */
         futures.add(future);
     }
     SimpleDateFormat sdf;
     sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss  ");
     for (Future<String> future1 : futures)
     {
         try {
             // Выводим в консоль полученное значение
             String text = sdf.format(new Date()) + executorCompletionService.take().get();
             System.out.println(text);
         } catch (InterruptedException | 
                  ExecutionException e) {}
     }
     // Останавливаем пул потоков
     executor.shutdown();
}  

// Класс, реализующий интерфейс Callable
 class CallableClass implements Callable<String>
 {
    String s;
    public CallableClass(String s)
    {
      this.s = s;  
    }

    
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception 
    {
       // Thread.sleep(1000);
        // наименование потока, выполняющего 
        // callable задачу
        System.out.println(s);
       
        readFromFile(s);
        return "From call: "+ s +". ThreadName:  "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" end";
    }
}
```

}

Ну и вызов в main где-то в цикле или вручную:

```
    FileArray.add("c:\\1\\file1.txt");  
    FileArray.add("c:\\1\\file2.txt");
    FileArray.add("c:\\1\\file3.txt");
    new ReadFile(FileArray);
```